# How do you adjust json config in Quarkus?

Tags: jackson, jsonb, jackson-databind, quarkus, thorntail

I am attempting to add a mixin to the [Jackson's `ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) in a [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io) project.  I have some code that looks likes this:

```java
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
        this.mapper = createObjectMapper();
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return mapper;
    }

    private ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.addMixIn(MyModel.class, MyMixin.class);
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

This code worked perfectly in a [Thorntail](https://thorntail.io/) project I had. For some reason, Quarkus isn't picking this up, and the object mapper is not affected. Is there something different I have to do with the Quarkus CDI?

### Updates

Apparently I was a little confused about the implementation.  I should be using the [Json-B](http://json-b.net/) api.  I figured out how to change the configuration for Json-B and posted it below.

Comment: Can you please share a reproducer project I could try?

Comment: Hmm, I have been looking into this more and it looks like I should probably be utilizing Json B.  I am not tied to Jackson, and I think the problem I was having was caused by the assumption that Jackson was the serialization implementation that quarkus was using.

Comment: Quarkus uses JSON-B by default. You should be able to see what's going on by looking at the quickstarts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of providing an `ObjectMapper`, you can provide a [`JsonbConfig`](http://json-b.net/docs/api/java.json.bind/javax/json/bind/JsonbConfig.html) so that you can customize serialization/deserialization.

Here is what I ended up using:

```java
@Provider
public class JsonConfig implements ContextResolver<Jsonb> {

    @Override
    public Jsonb getContext(Class type) {
        JsonbConfig config = new JsonbConfig();
        config.withPropertyVisibilityStrategy(new IgnoreMethods());
        return JsonbBuilder.create(config);
    }
   }

  class IgnoreMethods implements PropertyVisibilityStrategy {

    @Override
    public boolean isVisible(Field field) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isVisible(Method method) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This allows you to customize your `JsonbConfig`. Here, mine specifically prevents access of methods for serialization/deserialization. On [Quarkus with Panache](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache-guide), this prevents `isPersistent` from appearing in your JSON output.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the correct answer of @jsolum, here is a working provider which uses the fasterxml-annotations to check visibility of fields and methods:

```java
@Provider
public class JsonConfig implements ContextResolver<Jsonb> {

    @Override
    public Jsonb getContext(Class aClass) {
        JsonbConfig config = new JsonbConfig();
        config.withPropertyVisibilityStrategy(new PropertyVisibilityStrategy() {
            @Override
            public boolean isVisible(Field field) {
                JsonIgnore annotation = field.getAnnotation(JsonIgnore.class);
                return annotation == null || !annotation.value();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isVisible(Method method) {
                JsonIgnore annotation = method.getAnnotation(JsonIgnore.class);
                return annotation == null || !annotation.value();
            }
        });
        return JsonbBuilder.create(config);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`JsonbConfig` in Quarkus can be customized providing an `ApplicationScoped` instance of `JsonbConfigCustomizer` (taking @jsolum's answer into account):

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class JsonbFormattingConfig implements JsonbConfigCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(JsonbConfig jsonbConfig) {
        jsonbConfig.withPropertyVisibilityStrategy(new IgnoreMethods());
    }
}

class IgnoreMethods implements PropertyVisibilityStrategy {
    @Override
    public boolean isVisible(Field field) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isVisible(Method method) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Source: https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-json#json-b